# Control installation of other UWP app

Tags: uwp

Let's say I have two UWP apps in the store. The apps have the ability to launch each other. But for the case where the app being launched from the other has not been installed, I want to make the installation and launch of that app as seamless as possible.

(We can assume RS3.) I've seen [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/installing-uwp-apps-web), which streamlines the process down to a single click, which is nice. However, the users of the apps will likely have complex accessibility issues, so they may not be using a mouse/keyboard, or even eye tracking (they could be using switch scanning, for example).

Is it possible to 1) silently install/launch another app (I assume no - big security issues...) or 2) since the app installer is a UWP app itself, make my own app installer app that is accessible to our user's access methods?

I kind of assume that both of those options are not possible in UWP, but I wanted to see if there were other options I'm not aware of.

Comment: Apps are in store or on a server? Since you mentioned installing app from a web link, I assume they are on a server you have access to?

Comment: Is it correct that if they aren't on the store, the apps won't get updated or have the ability to deal with IAPs, etc? Was all the app-installer stuff added for RS3 just meant to deal with side-loaded apps?